# Optimize a SQL query for an event table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, optimization, indexing

In a SQLite db is a table with events that records changes to a certain entity in time.

There are thousand of these entities, whose parameters changes over time, so at each change we record the Timestep of change and the entire parameters set.

For example

```
------------------------------------
| NodeId | tStep | Param1 | Param2 |
------------------------------------
|   1    |  92   |  90    |  20.8  |
|   5    |  92   |  101   |  -2.4  |
|   5    |  108  |  38    |  -3.6  |
------------------------------------
```

I need to retrieve the state of an entity at a specific point in time, for example, at `tStep == 100` I should have `NodeId 1, Param1 == 90` and `NodeId 5, Param1 == 101` while at `tStep == 110` I should have `NodeId 1, Param1 == 90` and `NodeId 5, Param1 == 38`.

The following `Select` works fine, but I need to optimize the db so that the results are retrieved as fast as possible.

```
SELECT NodeId, tStep, Param1, Param2, MAX(tStep) FROM EventsTable
WHERE tStep <= ?
GROUP BY NodeId;
```

The only limitation is that I cannot put the Entity State for each tstep, because it would make the db huge.

I can add indexes, and other helper tables.

---

Expected (and effective) result:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| NodeId | tStep | Param1 | Param2 | Max(TStep) |
-------------------------------------------------  
|  1     |  92   |  90    |   20.8 | 92         |
|  5     | 108   |  90    |     0  |  108       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query works because SQLite *happens* to guarantee behavior that is non-standard and not supported by any other database.  Also, woe betide someone who adds `min(tstep)` to the query.  I strongly advise against depending on this (mis)functionality.

You should be doing:

```
select et.*
from eventstable et
where et.tstep < ?
order by et.tstep desc
limit 1;
```

For this query, you want an index on `eventstable(tstep)`.

EDIT:

If you need all node ids:

```
select et.*
from eventstable et
where et.tstep = (select max(et2.tstep)
                  from eventstable et2
                  where et2.nodeid = et.nodeid and et.tstep < ?
                 );
```

For this version, you need an index on `eventstable(nodeid, tstep)`.

Comment: This doesn't work. The result is ONE row with the MAX tstep and a random NodeId. I need to have all the NodeIds, that's why my query works: the table is grouped by NodeId and it selects the Max TStep within those groups.

Comment: SQLite guarantees the behaviour of [bare columns in an aggregate queries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg).

Comment: It takes forever to complete the edited query. As I explained the tables have a lot of records (in my little sample we have 882,180 records), that's why I need to optimize the table. My original query runs in 0.122s with tstep=100. Thanks.

Comment: @HappyCactus . . . Try it with the specified index.

Comment: Unfortunately the index doesn't fix the issue. The query takes forever to complete, while the other takes a fraction of seconds. This is why I asked for some optimization, even pre-calculation, organization of the data, some helper table, whatever.